# keeping a horizontal scrollbar to a canvas with a image to view the image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I am trying to keep a horizontal scrollbar to a canvas with an image to view the image which I want to stretch horizontally. When I grid the scrollbar, it displays the content in a different way.
Here is the Tkinter code,

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from ttkwidgets import CheckboxTreeview
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import PIL as pl

basePath = r'C:/'

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, path):
        self.nodes = dict()
        frame = tk.Frame(master)

        self.tree = CheckboxTreeview(frame ,height=28)
        self.tree.column("#0", width=300)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Select files', anchor='n')
        ysb = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)

        self.tree.grid()
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='w')

        frame2.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='n')
        canvas = tk.Canvas(master,bg="lightblue",height=300, width=680)
        canvas.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='s')
        self.img1 = Image.open(("logos/pic.jfif"))
        self.img1 =  self.img1.resize((1000,100))
        self.img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img1)
        canvas.create_image(101, 101,anchor='nw',image=self.img1)

        canvasHorizontalScroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas,orient = "horizontal",command = canvas.xview)
        #canvasHorizontalScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew') #this is where the scrollbar is being placed in the canvas

        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        self.insert_node('', abspath, abspath)
        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', self.open_node)

    def insert_node(self, parent, text, abspath):
        node = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=text, open=False)
        if os.path.isdir(abspath):
            self.nodes[node] = abspath
            self.tree.insert(node, 'end')

   def open_node(self, event):
       node = self.tree.focus()
       abspath = self.nodes.pop(node, None)
       if abspath:
           self.tree.delete(self.tree.get_children(node))
        for p in os.listdir(abspath):
            self.insert_node(node, p, os.path.join(abspath, p))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x600")
    global frame2
    frame2 = tk.Frame(root,bg="grey60",height=300,width=680)
    label2 = tk.Label(root,text='frame2',bg="grey60").place(x=340, y=10)
    app = App(root, path=basePath)
    root.mainloop()
```

And the output is something like this,
[image: window without scrollbar placement]

But when I uncomment the line to place the scrollbar with grid and then view the result, It is something different like this,

[image: window with scrollbar placement]

It pretty much hides the canvas and keeps a small scrollbar at the bottom. I could keep the horizontal scrollbar for the treeview frame but I couldn't do the same for this canvas. I just want a horizontal scrollbar to scroll and view the image in the canvas till the image ends

Comment: You have created the scrollbar as a child of canvas, so when `.grid(...)` is executed on the scrollbar, it will shrink the canvas to the size of the scrollbar.

Comment: Ok then, under what parent should I create the scrollbar?

Comment: You should use the same parent of canvas, i.e. `master`, and put it in `row=1` and `column=2` (one row below the canvas).  You need to remove `root.geometry(...)` in order to see the scrollbar.

Comment: The scrollbar and canvas are now visible, but the scrollbar is behaving in a weird way. The left and right buttons in the scrollbar are working but it seems like it's going infinitely without ending at the picture ending also I could notice touching and dragging the scrollbar is not showing the exact result. I think this is something to do with setting the scrollbar to adjust to the image view(size) or canvas view if the canvas size is adjusted to the image size.

Comment: It is because you have not configured `xscrollcommand` and `scrollregion` of the canvas.